# Passing a class as a parameter in Java

Tags: java, json, class, jackson

So I'm using the com.fasterxml.jackson readValue method, which works perfectly fine. It takes in a json String and a POJO that is populated and saved to obj:

```
Object obj = mapper.readValue(myJsonString, MyPojo.class);
```

For some reason, if I create a util class that does the same thing, I get an IO exception when I use the readValue() method.  When I print c, i get: "class models.UserProfile" . When I print out c.getClass(), I get "class java.lang.class". Is there something wrong with the way I'm passing the class?

```
    public static Object deserialize(String s, Class c) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    Object obj = mapper.readValue(s, c);
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Please show how you call `deserialize()`. `c` is correct - recall that it is an instance of a `Class` object, so the result of `c.getClass()` is to be expected (all objects have that method, which shows which class the object is an instance of).

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: Also, the stacktrace of your IOException would help.

Comment: What do you expect? You have declared `c` to have the type `Class` and yes, it has the type `java.lang.Class`. Just the same as `s` being declared to have the type `String` and `s.getClass()` will return `java.lang.String`…

Comment: I caught the exception and just ignored it previously. Now I did a printStackTrace() and realized what I did wrong. The util class was made by someone else and they used a different jackson library with the same method name

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic typing:

```
MyPojo obj = mapper.readValue(myJsonString, MyPojo.class);

public static <T> T deserialize(String s, Class<T> c)
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    return mapper.readValue(s, c);
}

MyPojo obj = Util.deserialize(myJsonString, MyPojo.class);
```

Your utility method however is using a static `mapper` which might not be such a good idea.

The weirdness found results from not using `c.getName()`. `c.getClass()` is of course `Class`.

The error is passing `c.getClass()` somehow. Or as likely: the mapper reused.

Comment: That doesn’t explain the I/O exception described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is probably `c.getName()` rather than `c.getClass()`.